# Large html file loading using iframe call

Tags: html, iframe, web

I have a web application which will have a iframe call to load a large (5000pages) html file and show on the application its loading and loading after some time browser crashing.So any best solution for this kind of issue.

Comment: You can always split this big html to small ones?

Comment: thanks for your response.We haven't split the html we have written some function on the document so is there any way to render the html file with out crash?